# WPF: Several two way bindings to same property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have some property in my data context.

```
public string SomeProperty {get; set;}
```

And I have two (or more) controls binded to this property. For example:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

This works fine, but I need to know what control have changed my property. Can I do this somehow?

Comment: Just an observation: if you're using MVVM the ViewModel shouldn't really be aware of its View at all, in fact you should be able to switch the View without affecting the behaviour of the ViewModel. As soon as your VM "need[s] to know what control have changed my property", then you've effectively bound your VM to a specific View, which is not really the "MVVM way" IMO.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's not the MVVM way. I will not do any functionality depending on this information. I just need to find out which control fires my setter. And I want to know if there is some way to do this in WPF.

Comment: Any of the three answers (at the time of writing) should work. @Blam's is the only one which will allow you to detect the change *within the property setter itself* although you didn't specifically state this as a requirement in your question. I would suggest trying all three solutions then upvoting and accepting the answer that you think solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have two public to the same backing variable

```
private string someproperty
public string SomeProperty1 
{
     get { return someproperty; };
     set
     {
         if (someproperty == value) return;
         someproperty = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeProperty1");
         NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeProperty2");
     }
}
public string SomeProperty2 
{
     get { return someproperty; };
     set
     {
         if (someproperty == value) return;
         someproperty = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeProperty1");
         NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeProperty2");
     }
}

<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty1, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty2, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

Comment: Although this works it doesn't scale very well. The OP specifically mentioned "two **(or more)** controls" (emphasis mine). That said, it's the only way of handling it in the ViewModel without using events.

Comment: @StevenRands Just how many TextBox you think there are going to be on one Window referring to the same value?  From a performance and resource perspective it scales just fine.  Unlike your answer it identifies which control "changed my property".

Comment: My answer works just fine, thanks very much, would you care to enlighten us as to why it doesn't?

Comment: The stated question is property.  In your answer the property setter is not aware of which control changed it.

Comment: That wasn't a requirement of the OP: "I need to know what control have changed my property" mentions nothing about having to do it in the ViewModel. Our answers are different ways of doing the same thing that are both equally correct given the requirements stated in the original question.

Comment: @StevenRands What?  Property is not limited to ViewModel.  No mention?  He included the property in his post.  public string SomeProperty {get; set;}  He even called it SomeProperty.

Comment: The OP stated: "some property in my data context". There is no mention of a ViewModel at all in the question or the question title.

Comment: Reading my comments back I'm not sure how ViewModel got into the conversation! Regardless, my answer does work and does answer the question of which control changed the property value.

Comment: I guess what I've been trying to say is that the OP did not state in the question that the detection of which control changed the property had to be done in the property setter itself.

Comment: @StevenRands Maybe "need to know what control have changed my property" is not clear to you but that is pretty clear to me.  He even posted his property and named it SomeProperty.

Comment: We obviously have a difference in interpretation of the question then, so I'll leave it there. I will say however that I don't appreciate the condescending tone that you have adopted in your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell inside your property setter, but the `TextBox` control does have a `SourceUpdated` event that can be used in conjunction with the `NotifyOnSourceUpdated` binding property.

In the XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="alpha"
        Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
        SourceUpdated="OnSourceUpdated" />
    <TextBox x:Name="bravo"
        Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
        SourceUpdated="OnSourceUpdated" />
</StackPanel>
```

In the code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _someProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_someProperty != value)
            {
                _someProperty = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SomeProperty"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    string _someProperty;

    void OnSourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox = (TextBox) sender;
        string message = string.Format(
            "Property value is '{0}' and was changed by TextBox '{1}'",
            SomeProperty, textbox.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use DependencyPropertyDescriptor:

```
    System.ComponentModel.DependencyPropertyDescriptor descriptor;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        descriptor = System.ComponentModel.DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextBox.TextProperty, typeof(TextBox));
        descriptor.AddValueChanged(txtbox1, TxtChanged);
        descriptor.AddValueChanged(txtbox2, TxtChanged);

    }
    public void TxtChanged(object sender, EventArgs ea)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("change from " + ((FrameworkElement)sender).Name);
    }
```